# How can I make my navigation bar links(About, Services, Projects) "stop running off the screen"-make it stop?

Tags: html, css

When I try to size down my desktop screen navigation size of 1440px(90em) to any lower width screen, my navigation bar links start dropping off the screen. I have tried using some media query combinations, but nothing to show for it.I haven't got much experience with frontend, so I am a little bit thin on this side. Any long-term fixes to this one?Any hint on this one will be highly appreciated.

HTML header code:

```
 <!--header-->
  <header>
    <nav class="nav__bar">
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="Sunnyside logo">
      </a>
      <ul class="nav__links">
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Project</a>
        </li>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-contact">Contact</a>
      </ul>
      <img src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="toggle menu icon" class="toggle__menu">
    </nav>
  </header>


CSS header styles:

    header {
    height: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav__bar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90em;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0 2em;
}

.nav__links {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav__item {
    margin: 1em;
}

.nav__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;

    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav__link:hover {
    color: hsl(232, 10%, 55%);
}

.toggle__menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: remove `width: 90em;` from `nav__bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, you set the color of the link text to white... it's white on white. But that's not fully the problem... you should also remove `width:90em` from the `.nav_bar`... it's unnecessary. see this codepen https://codepen.io/aequalsb/pen/jOmyJNp

Just simply allow the `<nav>` to "be itself"... which is a block level element and naturally attempts to stretch out to fit available width.

Comment: Solved it by changing 90em width to let's say 80% .

Answer (score 1):

padding in *CSS* Sizes the margin inside a button or element. Try using **`margin: (how many 'px' it's going off the screen);`** and I've had this problem before:

- SOLUTION 1:

use `margin-*left or top*: *px is going off screen*`

```html
<style>
#button {
width: 100px; /* the width of the button */
position: absolute;
left: 50%; /* always 50% when centering */
margin-left: -50px;   /* minus half the size of the element */
}
</style>
<button id="button">Center of page</button>
```

- SOLUTION 2

i've had this problem before, and in best situations, use `position: absolute` instead of `relative` if you are positioning the element.

```html
<head>
<style>
.background {
position: relative;
}
.overlap {
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- background-element -->
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Circle_Rufous_Solid.svg/1200px-Circle_Rufous_Solid.svg.png" class="background" width="10.5%" />
<!-- Overlap element -->
<img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_24930.png" class="overlap" width="10%" />
</body>
```

- SOLUTION 3

if none of the above works, consider using javascript: device tester command and redirect to an error page with unsupported devices.

**This example will detect a handful of mobile-devices, and if so, it'll redirect to ://.**

```html
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|Mahc|Macintosh|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
} else {

}
</script>
```

**NOTE:** if there is  big problem you cannot solve, and none of these work, its best to do research or find some articles to find your answer. Then consider using stackoverflow.

Comment: can we see some codepen examples of your solutions? i think you will find it rather difficult to apply the solutions you suggest... especially maintaining them over time

Comment: i was referring to post code snippets with an actual solution applied to the OP's problem... not just arbitrary examples